# HttpCookie exist local-IIS but IIS server it does not exist

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, httpcookie

I have the next code C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HttpCookie ckie = new HttpCookie("Juridico");
ckie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
ckie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

//le asigno el valor 1 en caso de que sea juridico
ckie.Values.Add("1", "1");
Response.Cookies.Add(ckie);
}
```

Local IIS it works fine, when I've published the solution the cookie not exist.

When I comment the line //ckie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1); 
already exist the cookie like localhost.

Thanks I hope you can help me.

Comment: Rare possibility but did you check server's clock? Is it set to correct time and date?

Comment: Yes it's the same to local machine. 
I have <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" /> in the web.config